# how to change a grouped data values in r

Tags: r, replace

I've the following grouped data (Section as my grouping variable). I would like to change the values in the Time variable based on the following criteria:
grouped_by(Section), the Time column values should be Time/nrow(Month). I tried the dplyr grouping function and replacing with the criteria but haven't been successful.

```
x <- data.frame(Section = c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A"), Month = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3), Time = c(10,10,10,20,20,20,20,30,30,30,30,30))
```

The expected outcome is:

```
X_updated <- x <- data.frame(Section = c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A"), Month = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3), Time = c(10/3,10/3,10/3,20/4,20/4,20/4,20/4,30/5,30/5,30/5,30/5,30/5))
```

Comment: Why do the Month values change between x and the expected outcome? There are 3 occurrences of 2 in x, but 4 occurrences of 2 in the expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may work for you:

```
x <- tibble(Section = c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A"), 
            Month = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3), 
            Time = c(10,10,10,20,20,20,30,30,30,30,30,30))
x %>% group_by(Month) %>% mutate(Time = Time / n())
# A tibble: 12 x 3
# Groups:   Month [3]
   Section Month  Time
   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
 1 A           1  3.33
 2 A           1  3.33
 3 A           1  3.33
 4 A           2  6.67
 5 A           2  6.67
 6 A           2  6.67
 7 A           3  5   
 8 A           3  5   
 9 A           3  5   
10 A           3  5   
11 A           3  5   
12 A           3  5
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Does it work for multiple grouping variables?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will do the trick, assuming you're grouping by both `Section` and `Month` to do your calculation properly:

```
new_x <- split(x, x$Section)
new_x <- lapply(new_x, function (y) {
  split(y, y$Month)
})
new_x <- lapply(new_x, function (y) {
  lapply(y, function (z) {
    z$new_time <- z$Time / nrow(z)
    return (z)
  })
})
new_x <- lapply(new_x, function (y) {
  do.call("rbind", y)
})
new_x <- do.call("rbind", new_x)
rownames(new_x) <- NULL
new_x$Time <- new_x$new_time
new_x <- new_x[, which(colnames(new_x) != "new_time")]
X_updated <- new_x
X_updated
```